# Fabric JS - draw a percent of a line between two points

Tags: javascript, geometry, fabricjs

So I can draw a line in Fabric JS;

```
var line = new fabric.Line([x1, y1, x2, y2], {
    stroke: 'red',
    strokeWidth: 0.9
});
canvas.add(line);
```

However I only want to draw perhaps half of the line or 20% of the line, so it needs to go from `x1,y1` but only be drawn 20% of the way towards `x2,y2`

The docs don't seem to offer this functionality, is there a way to do this in Fabric already? Or any anyone help with another solution?

Comment: Just calculate x2 to be 20% of your original x2 - x1 and pass that value in, same for y

Edit: Juan has an actual code snippet but you should know he's doing the same thing - calculating 20% of the original x2-x1

Comment: Yeah I see that now. Easy when you know how!

Comment: Hope I didn't come off rude, just wanted you to know it's as straightforward as that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ye Olde Maths approach:

```
var line = new fabric.Line([x1, y1, x1 + ((x2 - x1) / 5), y1 + ((y2 - y1) / 5)]
```

Should get you about 20% there on a straight line.